# Extending a ring hom from $R \to L$ to $K \to L$, where $K$ is fraction field of domain $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, fractions, integral-domain

Will this work as a proof?

> Let $R$ be a domain and $L$ a field.  Let $f : R \to L$ be a ring hom.  Let $K$ be the field of fractions of $R$.  Then to extend $f$ to $K$ means there is a map $f^* : K \to L$ such that $f^*|_R = f$.  The obvious choice for $f^*$ is that it respects precisely the fractions so that $f^*(a/b) = f(a)f(b)^{-1}$.  Let $g : K \to L$ be a ring hom that also restricts to $f$ on $R$.  Then $g(a/b) = g(a \cdot (1/b)) = g(a) \cdot g(1/b)$, but $1/b \equiv b^{-1}$ in field $K$ so that $g(a/b) = g(a)g(b)^{-1} = f(a) f(b)^{-1} = f^*(a/b). \ \ \ \ \square$

Thank you.  I am putting this into a flash card so don't want to write down an invalid proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the map is **well defined**. What does this mean? It means if we select two equivalent elements of the field of fractions $a/b \sim c/d$ then your definition of $f(a/b)$ and $f(c/d)$ give the same answer.